# Python - how to disconnect from a log file

Tags: python, logging, disconnect

Dears,

I face an issue with Python: I am creating a log file but once I run my program there is still a link between python and my log file: meaning I can't delete the log file and next log messages will be sent to this log file even if I want to send them elsewhere.

My workaround is to shutdown the kernel and restart but I would like to program it instead of doing it manually. Could you please advise?

My code:

```
import logging

#initialize the log settings
logging.basicConfig(filename='address.log',level=logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the FileHandler after using it. See the related article [python does not release filehandles to logfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435652/python-does-not-release-filehandles-to-logfile)

Comment: Hi thanks, I see it's related and that the problem mentioned is similar to mine but I am too novice to figure out how to adapt the solution provided to its specific code to mine...

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
logging.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do that this way:

```
log = logging.getLogger()
for hdle in log.handlers[:]:
    if isinstance(hdle,logging.FileHandler): 
        hdle.close()
        log.removeHandler(hdle)
```

I tried with `logging.shutdown()` but that doesnt work all the times.
You may like to visit [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15474586/3686202) as well for more explanation.