# Python: can't delete file after logging to

Tags: python

I'm writing to log file using the following code:

```
import logging
from gmplot import gmplot
logging.basicConfig(filename="sample.log", level=logging.INFO)
logging.debug("This is a debug message")
logging.info("Informational message")
logging.error("An error has happened!")
```

But then it's impossible to delete this file. how can I 'release' this file?

Answer (score 7):

You need to close() your logging:

As explained there:
[python does not release filehandles to logfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435652/python-does-not-release-filehandles-to-logfile)

When your Run class completes, call:

```
handlers = self.log.handlers[:]
for handler in handlers:
    handler.close()
    self.log.removeHandler(handler)
```

Comment: What would be the handler in the example of the question that must be closed?

Comment: If `handlers` is empty replace the first `self.log` with `logging.getLogger()` instead of `logging.getLogger(__name__)`.

Answer (score 4):

simply use logging.shutdown(), when you are done with logging.

Comment: This is the solution for those here getting `PermissionError`